# Remove Specific Content from div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you remove specific content from an element with jQuery?

So for example, if I had

```
<p>Hello, this is a test</p>
```

could I turn it into

```
<p>this is a test</p>
```

with jQuery (or any Javascript)

Please keep in mind that I just want to remove the "Hello, " so

```
$(p).innerHTML("this is a test");
```

wont work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = $('p').text()
str.replace('Hello,','');
$('p').text(str);
```

For more information visit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Please don't link to (or pay attention to) w3schools. They have nothing to do with the real W3, they're just a source of bad information and useless certifications.

Comment: I take this in note for futur answers. Thank you.

Comment: Mozilla has a really good JavaScript reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference), I usually start there.

Answer (score 6):

Do it like so:

```
$( elem ).text(function ( i, txt ) {    
    return txt.replace( 'Hello,', '' );
});
```

where `elem` is the reference to the DOM element which text content you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.

First get your element's HTML (if you have only one of them, use jQuery.each otherwise):

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var str = p.innerHTML;
```

Then, if you want to remove exactly "Hello, " do this:

```
str = str.substring(7);
```

If you want everything after the coma use:

```
str = str.split(',', 2)[1];
```

And set its HTML back with:

```
p.innerHTML = str;
```